# How can I partially expand a node in a TreeViewer?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, treeview, eclipse-rcp

I am using an Eclipse SWT TreeViewer. I have different types of items in my TreeViewer: `A` and `B`. `A` contains either more `A`s or `B`s. `B` can only contain other `B`s.

Fully Expanded Sample tree:

```
-A1
    B1
    -B2
        B3
    -A2
        -B4
            B5
```

Sample Expanded Tree (the way I want it to be:

```
-A1
    -B1
    -B2
        B3
    +A2
```

I am looking for a way to expand A1 that would expand all `B`s without expanding the nested `A`s.

I looked at the javadoc for the `AbstractTreeViewer` and saw all the expand methods. I don't think they fit my needs though because I don't want to expand the node to any specific level - I want to expand as many levels as each B node has, but not expand any A nodes.

Any help or pointers would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There isn't a clever way to do this. You will just have to work out which nodes to expand and call `setExpandedElements` to expand them.

Comment: Oh well. Thanks.